How can I check all the attributes (in same time) of some objects (same kind of) stored in a tuple?
I was trying to create a game.. (In Python) I made some objects with the same class. Then I made a function with (*) in the argument to get as many arg. as I want. But I guess, I got a tuple and now I need to iterate over all the object's attribute in an 'if' condition (attribute is a boolean). Please help! 
Raihan=Hero(name='Raihan',health = 200,weapon=Sword)
Cobra=Enemy(name='Cobra' ,health=140,weapon=Bow)

This function is the problem
 def valid(\*opponents: Character,\*,self):   
  if  self.health and >(opponents.health or opponents.health) != 0:        
    return True    
else:     
 return False

def main():

Raihan.equip(Sword)

input()

while valid(Cobra, self=Raihan):

    os.system('clear')

    

    Raihan.attack(Cobra)

    Cobra.attack(Raihan)

    input()

      


This works!
def valid(*opponents: Character, self: Character):
if  self.health and sum([i.health for i in opponents]) != 0:
    return True
else:
    return False

